# Как перебрать массив со словарями по определенному столбцу (ключу), начиная и заканчивая определенным индексом?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив со словарями:

```
let array = 
[
   { "Color":  "Белый",       "Count": 45,   "Price": 243  }, 
   { "Color":  "Оранжевый",   "Count": 1,    "Price": 653  }, 
   { "Color":  "Красный",     "Count": 67,   "Price": 33  },  
   { "Color":  "Зелёный",     "Count": 23,   "Price": 457  }, 
   { "Color":  "Синий",       "Count": 12,   "Price": 39  }
   { "Color":  "Желтый",      "Count": 50,   "Price": 300  }
];
```

Необходимо получить все значения столбца 3 (ключ "Price"), у которых значения ключа "Count" больше 5 (>5). При этом нужно начать поиск со второй строки и закончить четвертой.

То есть по итогу должны отобраться значения 33 и 457.

Подскажите, как на JavaScript реализовать данное условие?

Comment: Ну берите цикл, пробегайтесь  со второй строки по четвёртую... внутри нужно условие `if`....если элемент подходит под условие - складируйте его в новый массив...... в чём сложности - не ясно

Comment: array.slice(2, 4).filter(elem => elem.Count > 5).map(elem => elem.Price)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я разделил массив на часть с помощью метода `.slice`, после чего использовал `.filter` для фильтрации по количеству элементов (> 5) и вернул массив с ценой с помощью `.map`.

```js
const array = [
  { 'color': 'Белый',     'count': 45, 'price': 243 }, 
  { 'color': 'Оранжевый', 'count': 1,  'price': 653 }, 
  { 'color': 'Красный',   'count': 67, 'price': 33  },  
  { 'color': 'Зелёный',   'count': 23, 'price': 457 }, 
  { 'color': 'Синий',     'count': 12, 'price': 39  },
  { 'color': 'Желтый',    'count': 50, 'price': 300 }
];

console.log(array.slice(1, 4).filter(item => item.count > 5).map(item => item.price));
```